# How to setup SWC compiler

Tags: node.js, typescript, swc-compiler

I'm using [SWC](https://swc.rs) for the first time and I'm not able to compile my ts files into normal js files.

When I run my command :

```
npx swc ./src -d dist
```

I got the error :

```
failed to process js file

Caused by:
    0: failed to read swcrc file (src/index.ts)
    1: failed to deserialize .swcrc (json) file: syntax error: 1:1
    2: expected value at line 1 column 1
```

Here is my.swcrc I have generated with the [SWC Playground](https://swc.rs/playground)

```json
{
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "tsx": false
    },
    "loose": false,
    "minify": {
      "compress": false,
      "mangle": false
    }
  },
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs"
  },
  "minify": false,
  "isModule": true,
  "sourceMaps": "inline"
}
```

My goal is to :

- Take my ts files from my `./src` dir
- Compile and output it in a `dist` dir with source maps enabled